# Can I implement algorithmic differentiation in OpenMDAO using matrix seeds?

Tags: openmdao

My larger goal is implementing analytic derivatives for a generic structural eigenvalue problem.  Inside my model I develop the mass and stiffness matrices, and am using `scipy.linalg.eig` to solve for all eigenvalues/vectors. Currently, there are about 100 degrees of freedom in the finite element model (Euler beam elements), but only the first (smallest eigenvalues) three to five eigenvalue/vector pairs are of interest.  Eventually I would like to solve the problem using a reduced basis, but that isn't the current goal.

I am attempting to implement a modal method reverse algorithmic differentiation formula described in a recent paper by He, Jonsson, and Martins (https://doi.org/10.2514/1.J060726).  This formulation expresses the mass and stiffness matrix reverse seeds in terms of the eigenvalues, eigenvectors and the reverse seeds of both.  My understanding is that OpenMDAO and the MAUD architecture develops these seeds when total derivatives are computed.

Is this something that `compute_jacvec_product` and the Matrix-Free API would allow me to implement?  If so, do `d_inputs[]` and `d_outputs[]` correspond to the seed values?  Or is an algorithmic differentiation like this even possible to implement at the component-level in OpenMDAO?

I am also familiar with TACS and Mphys for structural problems, and am exploring if it might make more sense to incorporate those into my model rather than a from-scratch FE model...

**EDIT:**
I've implemented a quick explicit component for the eigenvalue problem, [linked here](https://github.com/peterjrohrer/modal_beam/blob/eig_derivs/eigenproblem.py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea. I can't be a lot more specific without some example code, but the d_inputs and d_outputs do in fact carry the seeds in forward and reverse modes for explicit components.

For Implicit components the reverse seed is carried in the `d_residuals` vector and the fwd seeds are carried in both the `d_inputs` and `d_outputs` vectors.

If you are trying to use AD, you might find the functional API helpful. It's new, and was specifically designed to help make AD more usable. Its not strictly required. You could obviously just write functions yourself, and then put a thing component wrapper layer around them. But the functional API is meant to let you avoid the wrapper boiler plate code.

Comment: Thanks! I've added a link to the component in the original question, my first implementation isn't throwing errors but optimization results suggest something isn't right.  I'll looking into the functional API more too!  In a quick read of the docs am I right that the functional API is limited to AD with jax? Or can a 'user-defined' AD solution be added?

Comment: The functional API can compute derivatives using AD with jax or can approximate derivatives using complex step or finite difference.  It doesn't currently support other AD libraries or user-defined AD solutions.